# How to change the read/write permission of SQLite database on windows?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I created a software using NetBeans and SQLite database. When I clean and build, the executable jar file and database work fine. It can read and write data from the database.

Then I created .exe file using "install creator" and after installing the software, the same dist folder is created in Program files on my Windows PC. When I run the executable jar file from that dist folder, it can only read the database, but can't write. I get this message

**java.sql.SQLException:attempt to write a readonly database**

Can anyone please help me solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

check this

The problem, as it turns out, is that the PDO SQLite driver requires that if  you are going to do a write operation (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE,DROP, etc), then the folder the database resides in must have write permissions, as well as the actual database file.

I found this information in a comment at the very bottom of the PDO SQLite driver manual page.

Comment: PDO driver is installed. I found a strange behavior. The db file works fine on desktop or other directories. But when I put the db into C folder it says "java.sql.SQLException:attempt to write a readonly database";

Comment: @anismizi May be  C drive is a protected area . Like Mostly the programs run in c drive  with the permission of administrator .So just try to change the accessibility permission of C drive.

Comment: Yes. everything works fine when I put the folder outside of program files in C drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.@Naveen Kumar Mishra

Answer (score 0):

You should write the user specific data to the Application Data folder of current user.

You can get the ROAMING directory from

```
String path = System.getenv("APPDATA");
```

Or if you want to make it platform independent you can use getProperty which will give you users home directory and then you can write to specific directory:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

You can form the sqlite on path like

```
String sqliteUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:"+path+"sample.db";
```

Comment: Tried it. But didn't work. I found a strange behavior. The db file works fine on desktop or other directories. But when I put the db into C folder it says "java.sql.SQLException:attempt to write a readonly database";

Answer (score 0):

Use this code line:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\Yourfile.db"`

I can say this is the proper way of crating DB without permission on to the drive like C:\

Answer (score 0):

Use this code line:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "\\databasefile.db"
```

I can say this is the proper way of creating DB in application folder on to the drive like C:\ without permission